# What path do I use in yarn 2 with plug 'n play to access a specific file in a package?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces, yarn-v2

This path was working `node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js` in the following command in Yarn 1...

```
yarn --cwd packages/mypackage/ node --trace-deprecation node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env env=dev
```

I moved to Yarn 2 (berry) with plug 'n play (PNP) and Workspaces so there's not a `node_modules` folder (the module I need is stored a zip file at `.yarn/cache/webpack-npm-5.64.0-a89fa9e176-9d32a61d98.zip`. The file within the zip upzips to `/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js`.

Here's what I tried, but I'm getting a path error, so have the path wrong still...

```
yarn workspace @myworkspace/mypackage node --trace-deprecation .yarn/plugins/@webpack-npm/bin/webpack.js --env env=dev
```

If there's a better way to do this that doesn't require writing out this whole path, I'm all for that too.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by the [Yarn Docs](https://yarnpkg.com/features/pnp) PnP is now the standard mode for package installation and should automatically create a `.pnp.cjs` file. You may have to add

```
require('./.pnp.cjs').setup();
```

to your script and/or run

```
node -r ./.pnp.cjs ./server.js
NODE_OPTIONS="--require $(pwd)/.pnp.cjs" node ./server.js
```

as stated in the docs. 

 Look [here](https://yarnpkg.com/features/pnp#packages-are-stored-inside-zip-archives-how-can-i-access-their-files) on how to access your zip file in a function. It should be as easy as `require.resolve(webpack/bin/webpack.js)`